# How do I ensure there is only a single running instance of my application?

Tags: wpf

I created a small program in WPF. When I run my exe file, it will open my application correctly. However, when I run my exe again, it will open another time. I would only like it to run a single time.

I searched the solution for this problem and I got some code like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

This code will close all the applications. However, what I need is when I run my exe again and again, there will only be a single instance of the application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the application to open only once when opening the same file again.

A way of doing that is not by killing a process (that might corrupt the file) but by immediately closing the freshly opened application.

Keep a list of open files some where central (registry, a file) and when the applications starts check whether or not the file is already in the list. If it is close the freshly started application.

You could try and add some code to bring the application that contains the requested file to the top of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) class.

- As there is always only **one** Mutex with a certain name **may exist per system**, you can instanciate it **during the startup** of your first application start.
- You can check each time the application is started if the application instance **can own the mutex.**
- If not, you know that there already exists another instance of the application and can gracefully close the new instance.

Working with the `Mutex` is very straightforward and easy.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Set this variable to false if you do not want to request  
        // initial ownership of the named mutex. 
        bool requestInitialOwnership = true;
        bool mutexWasCreated;

        // Request initial ownership of the named mutex by passing 
        // true for the first parameter. Only one system object named  
        // "MyMutex" can exist; the local Mutex object represents 
        // this system object. If "MyMutex" is created by this call,
        // then mutexWasCreated contains true; otherwise, it contains 
        // false.
        Mutex m = new Mutex(requestInitialOwnership, 
                            "MyMutex", 
                            out mutexWasCreated);

        // This thread owns the mutex only if it both requested  
        // initial ownership and created the named mutex. Otherwise, 
        // it can request the named mutex by calling WaitOne. 
        if (!(requestInitialOwnership && mutexWasCreated))
        {
           // The mutex is already owned by another application instance.
           // Close gracefully.

           // Put your exit code here...
           // For WPF, this would be Application.Current.Shutdown();
           // (Obviously, that would not work in this Console example.. :-) )
        }

        // Your application code here...
    }
}
```